# Increase number of edits before post becomes community wiki

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, editing, community-wiki

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/153352) on meta.stackoverflow.com:

> Posts enter community wiki mode when one of the following happens: [...]
>
> - The post has been edited ten (**10**) times by the original owner.

Typical answers on Code Review tend to be much longer than typical answers on other Stack Exchange sites, and so require more editing to get into decent shape. When an answer needs to be [several pages long](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/15895/11728) and contain [hundreds of lines of code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/15450/11728) in order to properly review the original poster's code, ten edits start to feel like an awkward constraint.

The [justification for the 10-edit limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123634/153352) is:

> [...] to discourage excessive bumping of questions. Every time you edit, your question is bumped to the front page, which you can use to get additional attention. The reputation loss associated with having your question made community wiki is supposed to deter users from bumping their questions continuously by making minor edits.

I'm quite aware of the 10-edit limit and so I do my best to avoid making unnecessary minor edits, but that means that I end up leaving typos and other small mistakes uncorrected for fear of "wasting" an edit.

So I'd like to suggest that the number 10 be increased on Code Review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of today, auto-CW conversion for posts has been disabled, therefore this request is now technically considered [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

The full announcement can be viewed [here](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2014/04/april-2014-newsletter/).  The first paragraph outlining this change is as follows:

> **No More Community Wiki Auto-Conversion**
>
> We have removed all of the formerly existing triggers that
>   automatically converted a post to Community Wiki. In their place,
>   there are now flags for moderator attention that are raised
>   automatically by the system. These flags will be raised when an author
>   makes over 10 edits to their post, when 10 users edit a single post,
>   when a question received 10 answers within a week, and when a question
>   receives 30 answers. Note that these last two are site-specific and
>   some sites that have higher answer count expectations will have these
>   thresholds increased.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround could be an external editor. It can save you a few edits.

I've been using one since my first Stack Overflow post because it helps accessing my posts when I'm offline.

Comment: I do exactly that (I compose answers in Emacs), but inevitably there are typos and omissions that I don't spot until I see my answer on the site.

Comment: @GarethRees: I usually paste them into LibreOffice to check the spelling before posting and copy code from Eclipse.

Comment: If you make several edits in quick succession (less than 5 minutes), they count as a single edit, so I think an external editor is not that useful. But if you do use it, [an extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/cs/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) that opens it automatically based on a text from a form might be useful.